# Issue with sticky nav bar not showing all dropdown options once page is scrolled downwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented a navigation bar within the site that I am trying to create, however, the only time all the dropdown options of the nav bar appear is when it's at the top of the page. Once I scroll down the page, the options become hidden behind one another. (If you look at the Profile button in particular, you can see a button behind the other due to the :hover being a different color.)

I've messed around a bit in the CSS with overflow and positioning. Making overflow show vs overflow hidden. I've removed the nav bar from the header to see if that was an issue, as well as remove the header from the HTML all together to see if there was an issue there.

```css
p {
 padding: 13px;
 text-align: justify;
}

.nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 top: 0;
}

.nav a {
 position: fixed;
 background-color: #333;
 z-index: 9999;
 overflow: show;
}

.nav a.home-btn {
 position: relative;
}

.nav a.logout-btn {
 position: relative;
}

#head1 {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 10px 14px;
}

* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 list-style: none;
 text-decoration: none;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar {
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: #333;
 font-family: sans-serif;
 z-index: 9999;
}

.navbar a {
 float: left;
 font-size: 16px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.profile-dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.profile-dropdown .profile-btn {
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

.profile-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.profile-content a {
 float: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.profile-content a:hover {
 background-color: gray;
}

.profile-dropdown:hover .profile-content {
 display: block;
}

.search-dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.search-dropdown .search-btn {
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

.search-btn:hover,
.profile-btn:hover,
.home-btn:hover,
.logout-btn:hover {
 background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.navbar a.logout-btn {
 float: right;
}

.search-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.search-content a {
 float: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.search-content a:hover {
 background-color: gray;
}

.search-dropdown:hover .search-content {
 display: block;
}

.listings-dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.listings-dropdown .listings-btn {
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

.listings-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.listings-content a {
 float: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.listings-content a:hover {
 background-color: gray;
}

.listings-dropdown:hover .listings-content {
 display: block;
}

.listings-btn:hover {
 background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.messages-dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.messages-dropdown .messages-btn {
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

.messages-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.messages-content a {
 float: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.messages-content a:hover {
 background-color: gray;
}

.messages-dropdown:hover .messages-content {
 display: block;
}

.messages-btn:hover {
 background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.settings-dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.settings-dropdown .settings-btn {
 font-size: 16px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

.settings-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #333;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.settings-content a {
 float: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.settings-content a:hover {
 background-color: gray;
}

.settings-dropdown:hover .settings-content {
 display: block;
}

.settings-btn:hover {
 background-color: #2ecc71;
}

.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/searchLost.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudfare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <body>
  <div class="header">
   <h1 id="head1">Lost And Found</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="navbar">
   <a href="mainPage.html" class="home-btn">Home</a>

   <div class="profile-dropdown">
    <button class="profile-btn">Profile<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="profile-content">
     <a href="index.html">Your Listings</a>
     <a href="#">Update Info</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="search-dropdown">
    <button class="search-btn">Search<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="search-content">
     <a href="#">Search Lost</a>
     <a href="#">Search Found</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="listings-dropdown">
    <button class="listings-btn">Listings<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="listings-content">
     <a href="#">Report Lost</a>
     <a href="#">Report Found</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="messages-dropdown">
    <button class="messages-btn">Messages<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="messages-content">
     <a href="#">New</a>
     <a href="#">Sent</a>
     <a href="#">Deleted</a>
    </div>
   </div>

   <div class="settings-dropdown">
    <button class="settings-btn">Settings<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="settings-content">
     <a href="#">Change Password</a>
    </div>
   </div>
   <a href="index.html" class="logout-btn">Logout</a>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar');

   window.onscroll = function sticky() {
    if (window.pageYOffset > nav[0].offsetTop) {
     nav[0].classList.add('nav');
    } else {
     nav[0].classList.remove('nav');
    }
   };
  </script>

  <p>
   Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the
   page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out
   the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page. Sample text to fill out the page.
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

What I want to happen is for the nav bar to show all drop down options regardless of the positioning of the nav bar, whether it be on top of the page scrolled all the way to the top, or on the top when scrolled down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a different css class for each of your drop downs, this will be challenging for you to work with and challenging for others to help you with. I fixed the Profile dropdown, the rest is up to you. Take it as a learning opportunity. You should use the same css class for all of the dropdowns, there isn't anything different enough about any of them to warrant having a class to just a given dropdown.

Also, next time you submit your code, us a `jsfiddle`
https://jsfiddle.net/3qwy26rp/22/

```
.profile-content {
display: none;
position: fixed;
background-color: #333;
min-width: 160px;
box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 1;
}




.profile-content a {
    float: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In dropdown memu need to use `position:fixed` and in the `<a>` tag need to use `position:relative` here is the `jsfiddle` link https://jsfiddle.net/0scmow82/16/. Hope this will be helpful for you